# Integral of the bessel function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

i have a qustion on the integration of a modified bessel function.
According to the reference:

Werner Rosenheinrich,"TABLES OF SOME INDEFINITE INTEGRAL
OF BESSEL FUNCTIONS OF INTEGER ORDER", 2017

$\int x^2 I_0(x)=x^2I_1(x)+\frac {\pi x}{2} (K_0(x)L_1(x)+K_1(x)L_0(x)) $

,where $I_v(x), K_v(x), L_v(x)$ is a modified bessel function of a first kind, that of a second kind, and a modified struve function respectively.

Is is possible to expand the solution of  $\int x^2 I_0(ax)$ in analytical way as the above equation?

Comment: Have you tried the change of variables $y=ax$?

Comment: The integral $\int x^2I_0(ax)\,dx=\frac{1}{a^3}\int y^2I_0(y)\,dy$, and you have the solution for the integral. You just put $y=ax$ at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I will try!